# Why is my Flask app unjustifiably slow when under load

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, gunicorn, psycopg2

I have a flask API that I made. To speak in general terms, it acts sort of like a Reddit clone, where users can upload, vote, and download. For database, I am using postgresql with sqlalchemy. I also use redis to cache and store sorting modes (hot, new, and top). Elasticsearch is used for searching the database. The app is served through Gunicorn with a more than powerful physical server that my company rents. (32 GB ram, 16 threads, and 16 cores). We then use Nginx reverse proxy so we can do https. Anyways, when I send a one-off request through postman, my response times are incredibly fast, often sub-200 ms. However, when I begin load testing with locust, my response times seem to climb exponentially with the number of requests I send. Around 100 requests per second can be handled in a timely fashion, but anything over that and the response time climbs to the multi-second range. If you could help reccommend configuration changes, or anything else you might think would work, it would be much appreciated. Also, if there are specific antipatterns I should scan the code for, please let me know. I will leave some details specific to the app below.

SQLAlchemy config options:

```py
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = db_url or os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = 20
    SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW = 100
    ELASTICSEARCH_URL = elastic_url or os.environ.get('ELASTICSEARCH_URL')
```

Initializing the app and database:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
mail = Mail(app)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = "admin_login"
```

[image: CPU Usage]

[image: Disk Usage]

[image: Testing results]

I can provide additional information upon request. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's unlikely that the bottleneck is in gunicorn or nginx, so I'd profile your application code. See which endpoints cause heavy load on the CPU and address those.

Comment: @AdamSmith Which tools would you recommend for profiling? Also, we've sort of deduced that the slow endpoints are the I/O heavy ones, like querying the database and committing to it. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Just the usual. If you're paying for an APM (New Relic, Datadog, Splunk, etc) use them as much as you can. If you're not, then try to target-test as well as you can and watch the metrics you can output. I've heard Zipkin and Jaeger can be of good help here but have never used them personally.

Comment: @AdamSmith Okay, thanks so much for your help. One final thing, is flask-profiler worth checking out?

Comment: I've never used it, but am not super familiar with running flask apps in production. I've used flask apps for dev and am familiar with developing and operating java apps at scale in production.

Answer (score 1):

"Measure, don't guess" - this was also a talk title by Mike Müller and is available on YouTube. That is an excellent Intro to profiling.

https://youtu.be/EcGWDNlGTNg

As a quick starter, I would have a look with py-spy, which is a profiler you can attach to a running process.

https://github.com/benfred/py-spy

As a last tip... You don't show any code, but I see you use Flask-Mail. Make sure to send E-Mails asynchronously.